# Search Engine Optimization reading material and references request

Tags: seo, reference

Search Engine Optimization (SEO) seems to be a topic I'm running into more and more and I would like to know a little more about it.

However, it seems to be very difficult to find any solid information about it. The [Wikipedia page on SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) has some general information and little bit of history, but nothing really concrete.

[Googling for anything SEO](http://www.google.ca/search?q=search+engine+optimization) oriented seems to return mostly SEO services for hire.

Does anyone have some articles, books or references they could point me to that could help deepen ones knowledge of SEO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by reading Google's [SEO starter guide](http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf).

Comment: Google should really follow its own advice: http://www.google.ca/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35291 has a pagerank of 0/10 according to their Google Toolbar, lol.

Comment: It's a rather new page and you also link to the .ca TLD. But have a look at the PR of http://www.google.ca/support it's enormous! :)

Answer (score 3):

[seomoz](http://www.seomoz.org) is a great resource.  You can also do a search on YouTube for SEO and there are some great introductory videos.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will be a great help for you regarding SEO. [SEO Link1](http://allanpollett.com/index.html) [SEO Link2](http://searchengineland.com/21-essential-seo-tips-techniques-11580) [SEO Link3](http://www.theseomethod.com/) [SEO Link4](http://www.seocompany.ca/seo/seo-techniques.html) [SEO Link5](http://www.seotechniques.co.uk/) [SEO Link6](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This you will get some good material

[Seo Material](http://www.vhghorecha.in/seo-650006-material/)